# CSS keyframe animation is not working on a react component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-hooks, css-animations

I want to animate the menu icon on my website to rotate 45 degrees (with some +-) when I click on it. The current setup I have (following [this](https://dev.to/samwatts98/how-to-easily-animate-your-react-components-on-click-with-css-keyframes-26mg) tutorial) is as follows:

`Navmobile.jsx`:

```js
const Navmobile = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      {
        <img
          className="open-button h-[3vh] w-auto"
          src={openIcon}
          onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
          open={open}
        />
      }
      {open && <Dropdown />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Navmobile.css`:

```css
.open-button[open="false"] {
  animation: rotate 500ms forwards; /* Animation titled rotate runs for 1s, once. */
}

@keyframes rotate {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }

  90% {
    transform: rotate(50deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

However, when I click on the button, nothing happens. I can get it to work through the css hover property, but not through React. I also tested it on different browsers, so doesn't seem to be a browser issue either.

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to `className` for your image `onClick`, not `open` atribute

```
<img
    className={`open-button h-[3vh] w-auto ${open ? 'open' : ''}`}
    src={openIcon}
    onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
/>

.open-button.open {
    animation: rotate 500ms forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the **false** value, because **open** property is custom and has no value. You just leave **open** in the square brackets.

```css
.open-button[open] {
  animation: rotate 500ms forwards; /* Animation titled rotate runs for 1s, once. */
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]